# Generate Two Arrays of Non-Duplicate Numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I have the following code which generates two non-duplicates arrays of integers based on a ratio. The codes works perfectly but for a 4000 line file, this takes some time.

```
//Train & Test numbers
int train = (int)(((double)Settings.Default.TrainingRatio / 100) * inputLines.Count());
int test = inputLines.Count() - train;

//Train & Test list
Random rnd = new Random();
var trainList = Enumerable.Range(1, inputLines.Count()).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).Take(train).ToList();
var testList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= inputLines.Count(); i++)
{
    if (!trainList.Contains(i))
        testList.Add(i);
}
```

And even worse, this is how i read those lines:

```
foreach (var n in trainList)
{
    objDataintilizer.GenerateMasterLableFile(inputLines.Skip(n - 1).Take(1).First().ToString());
}
```

Could anyone advice another way that could have a better performance.

Comment: What type is `inputLines`?

Comment: its a List<string> that contain lines

Comment: How are you reading those lines?

Comment: File.ReadLines(InputFile);

Comment: ahhh... for one please please change `inputLines.Skip(n - 1).Take(1).First()` to be simply.... `inputLines[n - 1]`. No idea why you take a 1000 miles detour, but one thing is for sure, it does not help your code to be faster, or even more readable.

Comment: inputLines is not a List<string>...it is a "System.IO.ReadLinesIterator". That is why what you suggesting won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your code calls `inputFiles.Count()`, you're effectively re-reading the entire file, since `File.ReadLines` is using *deferred execution*, and you aren't materializing it. Since you need the entire list in-memory anyway, use `File.ReadAllLines` instead, which returns a `string[]` and has a `Length` property, which is an O(1) operation instead of O(N).

Then, instead of using a `List<int>` for your `trainList`, use a `HashSet<int>` which will be faster to lookup with `Contains`:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return new HashSet<T>(enumerable);
    }
}

Random rnd = new Random();
var trainList = Enumerable.Range(1, inputLines.Length)
                          .OrderBy(x => rnd.Next())
                          .Take(train)
                          .ToHashSet();

var testList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= inputLines.Length; i++)
{
    if (!trainList.Contains(i))
        testList.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: I used part of your solution but i can't use the ReadAllLines because my file is huge and will cause an OutOfMemoryException. I have on question, do you think i can enhance reading the lines ?

Comment: If the file is huge, you can work on subsets of the file using `ReadLines`. You can iterate line by line as you go and create the list that way, instead.